# Drawing gl.POINTS and gl.TRIANGLES in same canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I am trying to figure out how I can draw triangles instead of points based on mouse events. The code is as fallows:

```js
var gl;

var points = [];
var tpoints = [];

var index = 0;
var cIndex = 0;

var dTri = false;
var dPoint = true;

var count = 0;
var counter = 0;

function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
  gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL isn't available");
  }

  var colors = [
    vec4(0.3921, 0.5843, 0.9294, 1.0), //Default
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), // black
    vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), // red
    vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), // yellow
    vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), // green
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), // blue
    vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), // magenta
    vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) // cyan
  ];

  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var m = document.getElementById("mymenu");

  m.addEventListener("click", function() {
    cIndex = m.selectedIndex;
  });
  var a = colors[cIndex][0];
  var b = colors[cIndex][1];
  var c = colors[cIndex][2];
  var d = colors[cIndex][3];
  gl.clearColor(a, b, c, d);

  //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

  var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
  gl.useProgram(program);

  var vbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * 200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

  var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16 * 200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    counter++;
    var i = index;

    x = 2 * (event.clientX - 12) / canvas.width - 1;
    y = 2 * (canvas.height - (event.clientY - 165)) / canvas.height - 1;
    var pts = [x, y];

    console.log(pts);
    if (dPoint || (dTri && counter % 3 != 0)) {

      points.push(pts);

    } else if (dTri) {
      index = index - 3;

      tpoints.push(pts);
      tpoints.push(points.pop());
      tpoints.push(points.pop());

      count++;
    }
    index++;

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * i, flatten(pts));

    t = vec4(colors[cIndex]);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16 * i, flatten(t));

  });

  render();
};

function drawTriangles() {
  dTri = true;
  dPoint = false;
  counter = 0;
}

function drawPoints() {
  dTri = false;
  dPoint = true;
}

function render() {
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, index);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, count);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function clearC() {
  var oldcanv = document.getElementById('gl-canvas');
  document.body.removeChild(oldcanv);

  var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
  canv.id = 'gl-canvas';
  canv.width = 500;
  canv.height = 500;
  document.body.appendChild(canv);

  index = 0;
  count = 0;
  init();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CG - Part2</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

  <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec4 vPosition; attribute vec4 vColor; varying vec4 fColor; void main() { gl_Position = vPosition; gl_PointSize = 10.0; fColor = vColor; }
  </script>

  <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float; varying vec4 fColor; void main() { gl_FragColor = fColor; }
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/MV.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = init;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
    <input type="button" onClick="clearC()" value="Clear">
    <input type="button" onClick="drawTriangles()" value="Draw Triangles">
    <input type="button" onClick="drawPoints()" value="Draw Points">
    <select id="mymenu" size="8">
      <option selected value="0">Default</option>
      <option value="1">Black</option>
      <option value="2">Red</option>
      <option value="3">Yellow</option>
      <option value="4">Green</option>
      <option value="5">Blue</option>
      <option value="6">Magenta</option>
      <option value="7">Cyan</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="500" height="500">
    Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
  </canvas>


</body>

</html>
```

As you can see the canvas uses the points array instead of the triangle points array to draw triangles. Can anyone see where im going wrong?

**UPDATED:**

```js
var gl, canvas, program, colors, menu;

var points = [];
var tpoints = [];
var cpoints = [];

var colorsP = [];
var tcolorsP = [];
var ccolorsP = [];

var pointIndex = 0;
var triangleIndex = 0;
var circleIndex = 0;
var colorIndex = 0;

var counter = 0;
var numTris = 100;
var degPerTri = (2 * Math.PI) / numTris;

var dTri = false;
var dPoint = true;
var dCircle = false;

var vbuffer;
var cBuffer;

function begin() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram(program);

    colors = [
        vec4(0.3921, 0.5843, 0.9294, 1.0), //Default
        vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // black
        vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // red
        vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // yellow
        vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // green
        vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // blue
        vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // magenta
        vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)   // cyan
    ];

    r = colors[colorIndex][0];
    g = colors[colorIndex][1];
    b = colors[colorIndex][2];
    a = colors[colorIndex][3];

    gl.clearColor(r, g, b, a);

    menu = document.getElementById("mymenu");
}

function init() {
    begin();

    vbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * 200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

    cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16 * 200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

    menu.addEventListener("click", function () {
        colorIndex = menu.selectedIndex;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, event);
        x = 2 * (mousePos.x - 5) / canvas.width - 1;
        y = 2 * (canvas.height - (mousePos.y - 5)) / canvas.height - 1;
        var pts = [x, y];

        counter++;

        console.log('Punkt : ', pts);

        if (dPoint || (dTri && counter % 3 != 0) || (dCircle && counter % 2 != 0)) {
            points.push(pts);
            colorsP.push(vec4(colors[colorIndex]));
        } else if (dTri) {
            pointIndex = pointIndex - 3;

            tpoints.push(pts);
            tcolorsP.push(vec4(colors[colorIndex]));

            tpoints.push(points.pop());
            tcolorsP.push(colorsP.pop());

            tpoints.push(points.pop());
            tcolorsP.push(colorsP.pop());

            triangleIndex++;
        } else if (dCircle) {

            pointIndex = pointIndex - 2;

            cpoints.push(pts);
            ccolorsP.push(vec4(colors[colorIndex]));

            cpoints.push(points.pop());
            ccolorsP.push(colorsP.pop());

            var xs = cpoints[0][0] - cpoints[1][0];
            var ys = cpoints[0][1] - cpoints[1][1];

            console.log('Diff x:',xs, ' Diff y:',ys);

            var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xs, 2) + Math.pow(ys, 2));
            console.log(radius);

            cpoints = [
                 cpoints[0][0], cpoints[0][1],
                 cpoints[1][0], cpoints[1][1]
            ];

            console.log('Punkt nr: 0', 'X Koordinat:', cpoints[0], 'Y Koordinat:', cpoints[1]);
            console.log('Punkt nr: 1', 'X Koordinat:', cpoints[2], 'Y Koordinat:', cpoints[3]);
            for (var i = 0; i < numTris; i++) {
                var index = 2 * 2 + i * 2;
                var angle = degPerTri * (i+1);

                cpoints[index] = (Math.cos(angle) / 4);
                cpoints[index + 1] = (Math.sin(angle) / 4);

                console.log('Punkt nr:', index, 'X Koordinat:', cpoints[index], 'Y Koordinat:', cpoints[index+1]);
            }
            circleIndex++;
        }
        pointIndex++;
    });
    render();
};

function drawCircles() {
    dTri = false;
    dPoint = false;
    dCircle = true;
    counter = 0;
}

function drawTriangles() {
    dTri = true;
    dPoint = false;
    dCircle = false;
    counter = 0;
}

function drawPoints() {
    dTri = false;
    dPoint = true;
    dCircle = false;
}

function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(points));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(colorsP));
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, pointIndex);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(tpoints));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(tcolorsP));
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleIndex * 3);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(cpoints));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(ccolorsP));
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 52 * (circleIndex * 2));

    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function clearC() {
    var oldcanv = document.getElementById('gl-canvas');
    document.body.removeChild(oldcanv);

    var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
    canv.id = 'gl-canvas';
    canv.width = 500;
    canv.height = 500;
    document.body.appendChild(canv);

    pointIndex = 0;
    triangleIndex = 0;
    circleIndex = 0;
    counter = 0;

    points = [];
    colorsP = [];
    tpoints = [];
    tcolorsP = [];
    cpoints = [];
    ccolorsP = [];

    init();
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I'm not a javascript master but here is code which is working:

```
var gl;

var points = [];
var tpoints = [];

var colorsP = [];
var tcolorsP = [];

var index = 0;
var cIndex = 0;

var dTri = false;
var dPoint = true;

var vbuffer;
var cBuffer;

var count = 0;
var counter = 0;

function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
  gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL isn't available");
  }

  colors = [
    vec4(0.3921, 0.5843, 0.9294, 1.0), //Default
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), // black
    vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), // red
    vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), // yellow
    vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), // green
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), // blue
    vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), // magenta
    vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) // cyan
  ];

  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var m = document.getElementById("mymenu");

  m.addEventListener("click", function() {
    cIndex = m.selectedIndex;
  });
  var a = colors[cIndex][0];
  var b = colors[cIndex][1];
  var c = colors[cIndex][2];
  var d = colors[cIndex][3];
  gl.clearColor(a, b, c, d);

  //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

  var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
  gl.useProgram(program);

  vbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * 200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

  cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16 * 200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    counter++;
    var i = index;

    x = 2 * (event.clientX - 12) / canvas.width - 1;
    y = 2 * (canvas.height - (event.clientY - 165)) / canvas.height - 1;
    var pts = [x, y];

    console.log(pts);
    if (dPoint || (dTri && counter % 3 != 0)) {
      points.push(pts);
      colorsP.push(vec4(colors[cIndex]));
    } else if (dTri) {
      index = index - 3;

      tpoints.push(pts);
      tcolorsP.push(vec4(colors[cIndex]));

      tpoints.push(points.pop());
      tcolorsP.push(colorsP.pop());

      tpoints.push(points.pop());
      tcolorsP.push(colorsP.pop());

      count++;
    }
    index++;
  });

  render();
};

function drawTriangles() {
  dTri = true;
  dPoint = false;
  counter = 0;
}

function drawPoints() {
  dTri = false;
  dPoint = true;
}

function render() {
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(points));
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(colorsP));
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, index);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(tpoints));
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(tcolorsP));
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, count*3);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function clearC() {
  var oldcanv = document.getElementById('gl-canvas');
  document.body.removeChild(oldcanv);

  var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
  canv.id = 'gl-canvas';
  canv.width = 500;
  canv.height = 500;
  document.body.appendChild(canv);

  index = 0;
  count = 0;
  init();
}
```

What was wrong and what I've done:

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, count); -> gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, count*3);
```

drawArrays require number of points, so 3 * number of triangles.

I assumed that you wanted separate points from triangles, so you cannot mix triangles vertices and points. After each mouse clicks you were sending data about 1 point and its color. And never change previous data so `gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, index);` was working fine. But then you want to draw triangles so you need to provide new data. You were storing triangle's vertices in `tpoints` but never send it into GPU memory. So you need to create 4 buffers(2 positions, 2 colors) in 2 VAOs or (which is simpler and I showed it above) copy data twice for every frame - once providing data for points and once for triangles.

I hope it was helpful, feel free to ask more questions.

### EDIT:

```
var gl, canvas, program, colors, menu;

  var points = [];
  var tpoints = [];
  var cpoints = [];

  var colorsP = [];
  var tcolorsP = [];
  var ccolorsP = [];

  var pointIndex = 0;
  var triangleIndex = 0;
  var circleIndex = 0;
  var colorIndex = 0;

  var counter = 0;
  var numTris = 20;
  var degPerTri = (2 * Math.PI) / numTris;

  var dTri = false;
  var dPoint = true;
  var dCircle = false;

  var vbuffer;
  var cBuffer;

  function begin() {
      canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
      gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
      if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }

      gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
      gl.useProgram(program);

      colors = [
          vec4(0.3921, 0.5843, 0.9294, 1.0), //Default
          vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // black
          vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // red
          vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // yellow
          vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  // green
          vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // blue
          vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // magenta
          vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)   // cyan
      ];

      r = colors[colorIndex][0];
      g = colors[colorIndex][1];
      b = colors[colorIndex][2];
      a = colors[colorIndex][3];

      gl.clearColor(r, g, b, a);

      menu = document.getElementById("mymenu");
  }

  function init() {
      begin();

      vbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * 200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

      cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 16 * 200, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

      menu.addEventListener("click", function () {
          colorIndex = menu.selectedIndex;
      });

      canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
          var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, event);
          x = 2 * (mousePos.x - 5) / canvas.width - 1;
          y = 2 * (canvas.height - (mousePos.y - 5)) / canvas.height - 1;
          var pts = [x, y];

          counter++;

          console.log('Punkt : ', pts);

          if (dPoint || (dTri && counter % 3 != 0) || (dCircle && counter % 2 != 0)) {
              points.push(pts);
              colorsP.push(vec4(colors[colorIndex]));
          } else if (dTri) {
              pointIndex = pointIndex - 3;

              tpoints.push(pts);
              tcolorsP.push(vec4(colors[colorIndex]));

              tpoints.push(points.pop());
              tcolorsP.push(colorsP.pop());

              tpoints.push(points.pop());
              tcolorsP.push(colorsP.pop());

              triangleIndex++;
          } else if (dCircle) {

              pointIndex = pointIndex - 2;

              var p2 = pts;
              var p1 = points.pop();

              var c2 = vec4(colors[colorIndex]);
              var c1 = colorsP.pop();

              var xs = p1[0] - p2[0];
              var ys = p1[1] - p2[1];

              console.log('Diff x:',xs, ' Diff y:',ys);

              var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xs, 2) + Math.pow(ys, 2));
              console.log(radius);

              console.log('Punkt nr: 0', 'X Koordinat:', p1, 'Y Koordinat:', cpoints[1]);
              console.log('Punkt nr: 1', 'X Koordinat:', cpoints[2], 'Y Koordinat:', cpoints[3]);
              for (var i = 0; i < numTris; i++) {
                var angle1 = degPerTri * (i);
                var angle2 = degPerTri * (i+1);
                var pt2 = vec2(Math.cos(angle1)*radius, Math.sin(angle1)*radius);
                var pt3 = vec2(Math.cos(angle2)*radius, Math.sin(angle2)*radius);
                var p2 = vec2(p1[0]+pt2[0], p1[1]+pt2[1]);
                var p3 = vec2(p1[0]+pt3[0], p1[1]+pt3[1]);
                cpoints.push(p1);
                cpoints.push(p2);
                cpoints.push(p3);

                ccolorsP.push(c1);
                ccolorsP.push(c2);
                ccolorsP.push(c2);

              }
              console.log(cpoints);
              circleIndex++;
          }
          pointIndex++;
      });
      render();
  };

  function drawCircles() {
      dTri = false;
      dPoint = false;
      dCircle = true;
      counter = 0;
  }

  function drawTriangles() {
      dTri = true;
      dPoint = false;
      dCircle = false;
      counter = 0;
  }

  function drawPoints() {
      dTri = false;
      dPoint = true;
      dCircle = false;
  }

  function render() {
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
      gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(points));
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
      gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(colorsP));
      gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, pointIndex);

      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
      gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(tpoints));
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
      gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(tcolorsP));
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleIndex * 3);

      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
      gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(cpoints));
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
      gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(ccolorsP));
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3*circleIndex*numTris);

      window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  function clearC() {
      var oldcanv = document.getElementById('gl-canvas');
      document.body.removeChild(oldcanv);

      var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
      canv.id = 'gl-canvas';
      canv.width = 500;
      canv.height = 500;
      document.body.appendChild(canv);

      pointIndex = 0;
      triangleIndex = 0;
      circleIndex = 0;
      counter = 0;

      points = [];
      colorsP = [];
      tpoints = [];
      tcolorsP = [];
      cpoints = [];
      ccolorsP = [];

      init();
  }

  function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
      };
  }
```

What I've changed:

```
var numTris = 20;
```

with `gl.bufferData` you allocate some memory on GPU and copy some data(or not). With `gl.bufferSubData` you only copy data without allocating any memory. If your data will be bigger than allocated memory you will be in big trouble.

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3*circleIndex*numTris);
```

With `gl.TRIANGLE_FAN` you wouldn't be able to draw multiple circles as triangles in fans are connected. I also removed magic constant.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numTris; i++) {
  var angle1 = degPerTri * (i);
  var angle2 = degPerTri * (i+1);
  var pt2 = vec2(Math.cos(angle1)*radius, Math.sin(angle1)*radius);
  var pt3 = vec2(Math.cos(angle2)*radius, Math.sin(angle2)*radius);
  var p2 = vec2(p1[0]+pt2[0], p1[1]+pt2[1]);
  var p3 = vec2(p1[0]+pt3[0], p1[1]+pt3[1]);
  cpoints.push(p1);
  cpoints.push(p2);
  cpoints.push(p3);

  ccolorsP.push(c1);
  ccolorsP.push(c2);
  ccolorsP.push(c2);
}
```

You were doing some crazy things here, assigning some value into `cpoints` than changing it, mess. Here I push 3 positions and 3 colors for every triangle in circle. Sorry about extra assignments but javascript string concatenation instead of addition drives me crazy ;) `p1` is also center of the circle

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation. Can you explain abit more about the "Copy data twice for every frame part"?. Cause I actually tried the solution with 4 buffers (2 position buffers and 2 color buffers). But your solution is more natural I think. And now I need to draw circles aswell so how could I extend it without creating 2 more buffers (1 position and 1 color) ?

Comment: Sure, you copy data about points into GPU and draw it, then you copy data about triangles into the same GPU memory and draw it. You could add another buffer for circles, but probably you will draw many triangles as circle so you could just add this triangles to previous buffer.

Comment: I've just updated my question with my code where i'm trying to implement the circle functionality. My circle is being rendered in the center of the canvas no matter what I do.. Can you see where im wrong?